# Laravel migration foreign key issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have created categories table using categories migration and then i am trying to create products table using another migration with foreign key categories_id in products table to id in products table.

Please find my migrations below.

```
Categories migration

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriesTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories',function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('category_name', 255);
            $table->string('category_description', 255);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categories');
    }

}

Products migration

<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductsTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->reference('id')->on('categories');
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->text('product_description');
            $table->decimal('product_cost', 10, 2);
            $table->text('product_image');
            $table->boolean('product_availability')->default(1);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('products');
    }

}
```

I am getting this below error when i ran php artisan migrate command in command line

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i
n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v
ersion for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `pr
oducts` add constraint products_category_id_foreign foreign key (`category_
id`) references `categories` ())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this (Notice `unsigned` and `references` you have used `reference`):

```php
// unsigned() should be used during declaration
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();

// reference() should be references()
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

### Update:

At first create the `products` table then add `foreign` key. Remove the following line when creating the table:

```php
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

Then add foreign key using this:

```php
Schema::table('products', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});
```

Both should be different like this:

```php
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('product_name');
    // more ...
});

Schema::table('products', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
});
```

Comment: I checked already that thread I tried those but no difference by the way i checked my db also tables get created and the foreign key was unsigned in both tables. The problem is because of this error i can't migrate future migrations

Comment: Also, if 'references()' is misspelled, it would cause the same issue :)

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned()` should be defined while setting the type, not while setting the foreign key. Also, `reference()` should be `references()`

The corresponding lines should be changed like this:

```
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
```

Comment: Still same error persists even after adding unsigned() before froeign key assigning

Comment: Have you fixed the references ?

Comment: yeah please check above approved answers